# jquery: how can I stop appendTo from happening instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, delay, appendto

I have been googling and trying for the life of me to delay appendTo from happening instantly, so that I can do a nice fadeout first.  Here, myObject is a link:

```
<a href="#">My Link</a>
```

And I would like to move it into an unordered list:

```
<div id="newDiv">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

By doing something like this:

```
myObject.fadeOut(300).appendTo('#newDiv ul').fadeIn(300);
myObject.wrap('<li></li>');
```

I know that appendTo isn't an animation object though, so it just happens instantly.  So I tried putting the append as a callback to fadeOut:

```
myObject.fadeOut(300, myObject.appendTo('#newDiv')).fadeIn(300);
myObject.wrap('<li></li>');
```

Only now it not only happens instantly, the wrap no longer works.  I've also tried using a setTimeout to delay the appending to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
myObject.fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).appendTo('#newDiv ul').fadeIn(300) });
```

By doing the "appendTo" in the callback from the fade, you can wait until the fade is done. All (as far as I know) the jQuery animation effects take callbacks like that.

Comment: His callback wasn't really a callback originally.  The whole point of a callback is that it's a function that will be called when the original task is completed, but passing myObject.appendTo('...') prematurely calls appendTo and passes its return value as the callback parameter.

Comment: Yes, the curiously-named @OlduvaiHand is correct. The "callback" in the OP wasn't a callback at all.